# Using Derived function from base class

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance

I have a class `test_d` which publicly inherits class `test_b`. The class `test_d` has a function `getValues()` which I need to call using an object of class `test_b`. I tried using `dynamic_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` but it didn't work. Is there any other way to do that?

```
class test_b {
// this is the base class
};

class test_d : public test_b {
// this is the derived class

public int getValues() const; // this is the function I need to use.
};

test_b* objB = new test_d;
dynamic_cast<test_d*>(objB)->getValues(); // this is what I am doing.
```

Comment: That sounds like a heavily flawed design ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it didn't work"? The `dynamic_cast` looks like it should have worked (ignoring the fact that base classes should not know about their derived types.)

Comment: seems like some broken OOP

Comment: Why isn't getValues a virtual function in the base class?

Comment: `public int getValues() ...` is not a valid C++ code, it's Java. You need a colon after `public` like `public:`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am not able to compile the code. The object can't access the function.

Comment: Post some (minimal) real code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your interface you should declare your method as pure virtual function and then in your derived class you should write an implementation

```
class test_b 
{
public:
    virtual int getValues() const = 0;
};

class test_d : public test_b 
{
public:
    virtual int getValues() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }
};
```

And from somewhere of your `main()`:

```
test_b* objB = new test_d;
objB->getValues();
```

this is the basics of OOP: the interface and an implementation of the interface